# Why does sudo -H pip -V differ from pip -V?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python, sudo, pip

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895381/different-version-of-pip-installed-when-using-sudo) but my root's path has no access to `pip`.

Here is my terminal output.

```
lxa@lxa-pc:~$
lxa@lxa-pc:~$ sudo -H pip -V
[sudo] lxa 的密码:
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
lxa@lxa-pc:~$ pip -V 
pip 9.0.1 from /home/lxa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5) 
root@lxa-pc:~$ echo $PATH 
/home/lxa/bin:/home/lxa/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
lxa@lxa-pc:~$ sudo su
lxa@lxa-pc:/home/lxa# 
echo $PATH 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
lxa@lxa-pc:/home/lxa#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip 8.1.1 is the version of python-pip from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. When installing a package with pip set the HOME environment variable to the home directory specified by the target user's password database entry by using the option `-H`.

In the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895381/different-version-of-pip-installed-when-using-sudo) two different versions of pip were installed. To find out why `pip -V` returns a more up-to-date version of pip (pip 9.0.1) which is also installed, run the following commands:

```
sudo -H pip -V
```

This command returns `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` in a default Ubuntu 16.04 installation. The command `sudo -H pip3 -V` returns `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)` in a default Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

```
which python3
```

This command returns `/usr/bin/python3` in a default Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

```
which pip
```

This command returns `/usr/bin/pip` in a default Ubuntu 16.04 installation. The command `which pip3` returns `/usr/bin/pip3` in a default Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

Comment: But where is the executable pip8.1.1 exits. I considered the environment variable equals to ```echo $path in root```(as my screenshot) when I use -H.Am I right? But when I  input ```sudo -H pip -V```,it said ```pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages ```,but this path is not in my root's environment variable.so I want to find where the pip8.1 exits.How the ubuntu1604 find it..Thank you!   @karel

Comment: … or as a single command and nicely formatted: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(*sys.path, sep="\n")'`

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` shows the Python path. If the variable has not been set it will be blank. If it is blank, please comment about the results of running this command to show the Python path: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(*sys.path, sep="\n")'`

Comment: Maybe add that in order to update pip, you can execute `pip install -U pip`?